# How do I Create a interactive modal sliding up/down?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a modal that is half screen but when the use slides up, it becomes full screen. Like google map or lyft's modal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-bottom-action-sheet](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-bottom-action-sheet), it's the easiest solution if you have time and are willing to experiment you can create your own custom solution using [PanResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) from react-native